# Second Stiefel-Whitney class of $\mathbb{C}\text{P}^2\#\overline{\mathbb{C}\text{P}^2}$

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes, 4-manifolds

I know that $w_2(\mathbb{C}\text{P}^2\#\overline{\mathbb{C}\text{P}^2})\neq 0$, where $\overline{\mathbb{C}\text{P}^2}$ is $\mathbb{C}\text{P}^2$ with opposite orientation. But how do you prove this? I can't figure it out and I haven't found a single reference justifying it (I suppose it should be quite elementary...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second Stiefel Whitney class of $Y=\mathbb{CP}^2$ is non-trivial. Similarly for $Z=\mathbb{CP^2}\setminus \{pt\}$. Namely the inclusion $Z\rightarrow Y$ pulls back the tangent bundle from $Y$ to $Z$, and on cohomology it induces an isomorphism on $H^2(\cdot;\mathbb{Z}_2)$.

Consider now the inclusion $i:Z\rightarrow X$, where $X$ is the space of the OP. The tangent bundle is again pulled back to Z, and $i^*(w_2(X))=w_2(Z)\not=0$. Thus $w_2(X)\not=0$.

This is a more general phenomenon: The first stiefel whitney class of a vector bundle over a $CW$ complex: i.e. if the bundle orientable or not , only depends on the restriction of the bundle over the one skeleton. Something similar is true of the second Stiefel Whitney class over the two-skeleton.

Comment: Thank you for your response!
One question however: how does $\mathbb{C}\text{P}^2$ lie in $\mathbb{C}\text{P}^2\#\overline{\mathbb{C}\text{P}^2}$? We remove a disk from $\mathbb{C}\text{P}^2$ to take the connected sum, so I don't see how we can say that it lies entirely in it...

Comment: Think about $S^2$ with a point or a disc removed. In bout cases you can find an inclusion of $S^2-pt$ into it.

Comment: Same happens here

Comment: @JasonDeVito exactly, that's what I thought. But the map $\mathbb{C}\text{P}^2\setminus\{pt\}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}\text{P}^2\#\overline{\mathbb{C}\text{P}^2}$ is only homotopy equivalent to the inclusion $\mathbb{C}\text{P}^2\setminus\{D^4\}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}\text{P}^2\#\overline{\mathbb{C}\text{P}^2}$, it's not a genuine inclusion map, right?

Comment: @Kafka91:  Well, if you'd like, in the definition of $Z$, just change $pt$ to $D^4$.    The two $Z$s are diffeomorphic, as Thomas alludes to in his first comment.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: thanks

Comment: @ThomasRot Does this imply that the second Stiefel-Whitney class of the connected sum of $\mathbb{C}\text{P}^2$ with any other 4-manifold is non-trivial? Because I don't see how we are using the fact that we take the connected sum with $\overline{\mathbb{C}\text{P}^2}$...

I seem to be getting contradictory conclusions when considering this method compared to using the formula from here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2062853/stiefel-whitney-classes-and-connected-sum.

Comment: @Kafka91: Yes this is true. The formula in your link also states this.

Comment: @ThomasRot: Oh, yes, right! I see where I was making a mistake. Thanks a lot!