# Tangent bundle of the connected sum of two smooth manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

Let $M,N$ be two smooth connected real $n$-dimensional manifolds. Suppose they are both orientable for simplicity. Let $i:D_1\hookrightarrow M$ and $j:D_2\hookrightarrow N$ two embedded disks so that $i$ preserves the orientation and $j$ reverses the orientation. Consider their connected sum given by \begin{equation*}M\#N=(M\setminus\overset{\circ}D_1)\sqcup_\phi(N\setminus\overset{\circ}D_2)
\end{equation*}where $\phi:\partial D_1\rightarrow\partial D_2$ is a diffeomorphism glueing the boundary of the two disks. The hypothesis on $j$ to reverse the orientation is given in order to ensure that $M\#N$ is orientable.

*At this point I would like to know if there is a canonical approach to understand how the tangent space at a point of the connected sum looks like and if this can help us to have global information on the tangent bundle. Why Am I asking that?*

I want to understand some characteristic classes associated to the connected sum. For example we can consider the total Stiefel-Whitney class $w(M\#N)\in H^*(M\#N, \mathbb{Z}_2)$ or the Euler class $e(M\#N)\in H^n(M\#N,\mathbb{Z})$. I was thinking about the case when the tangent bundle splits as a direct sum (product of manifold $M\times N$) and so by using Whitney product formula for the Stiefel-Whitney class we can recover $w(M\times N)$ from $w(M)$ and $w(N)$. In particular this seems to me no longer true for the connected sum even in the simplest case of connected compact and orientable surface.

**Question**

> Is there a canonical approach to understand how $T(M\#N)$ looks like and to get information on its characteristic classes? Or better, is there a way to understand how for example $w(M\# N)$ looks like by  using only the axioms and using only the construction of the connected sum?

Comment: At points interior to $M$ with the disc removed, the tangent bundle just looks like that of $M$. Similarly at points interior to $N$ minus disc. At the boundary, the tangent space $T_x(M\setminus D_1)=T_xM$ gets identified with $T_{\varphi(x)}(N\setminus D_2)=T_{\varphi(x)}N$ via the isomorphism $d\varphi_x$. So the tangent bundle $T(M\#N)$ is the result of gluing $TM$ and $TN$ together along $T\partial(M\setminus D_1)$ and $T\partial(M\setminus D_2)$ via the map $d\varphi$.

Comment: One approach is to choose arbitrary points $p\in M$, $q\in N$ and write $M\#N=A\cup B$, where $A\cong M\setminus\{p\}$, $B\cong N\setminus\{q\}$, and $A\cap B\cong S^{n-1}\times(0,1)$. The resulting Meyer-Vietoris sequence can be useful for describing the cohomology of $M\#N$.

Comment: Thanks to both. @Kajelad if the manifolds are both orientable then it is also the connected sum and the top cohomology should be isomorphic to the integer. Can I deduce from this that $e(M\# N)$ is a combination of $e(M),e(N)$? Same question for the total Stiefel-Whitney sum. I mean, by computing the cohomology as you suggested it seems to me that such characteristic classes have to be sum of the characteristic classes of the starting manifolds.

Comment: @John117 These classes are elements of cohomology over different spaces, so one must carefully define how to "combine" them. You can describe the Euler relation using the Euler characteristic $\chi(M\# N)=\chi(M)+\chi(N)-\chi(S^n)$. It seems the Stiefel-Whitney numbers also add modulo 2, as seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2062853/stiefel-whitney-classes-and-connected-sum).

Comment: @Thorgott I'm not sure that's correct. If I glue $S^2$ to itself (self connected sum by removing two-disks) I have $T^2$ but the tangent bundles don't look the same. $SO(3)$ vs $T^2 \times R^2$ for points interior to the two sphere

Comment: @R.Rankin The connected sum of $S^2$ with itself means taking two copies of $S^2$, removing a disk from each and gluing along the respective boundaries. That just gives $S^2$ again. What you describe sounds like you want to remove two disks from a single copy of $S^2$ and then glue along the respective boundaries. That does give $T^2$, but it's just a different process, so I don't quite understand your point. An analogous description holds for this "self-connected sum" as well, though.

Comment: @Thorgott thank you, that clears that up